# How can I convert an array of integers into a BST? - in particular how can I initialise the BST, then add nodes to this root?

Tags: python, arrays, binary-search-tree

I am given an `array of integers` and I would like to convert into a `BST`;

```
class BST: 
    def __init__(self,value): 
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.value = value

    def insert(self, value):
        if value<self.value: 
            if not self.left: 
                self.left = BST(value)   
            else: 
                self.left.insert(value)   
        else: 
            if not self.right: 
                self.right = BST(value)  
            else: 
                self.right.insert(value)
        return self

array = [3,10,5,2,7,6,11] 

def insertArrayEntryIntoBst(array): 
    currentNode = BST()
    for i in range(len(array)):  
        currentNode.insert(array[i])
```

Challenges that I have:

1. How do I `initialise the BST`? - in the `insert() function` do I need to start with a line that reads `if not currentNode: BST(array[0])`?
2. After initialising, is my code correct for `insertArrayEntryIntoBst()`? The idea is simply to loop through the input array and let the `insert()` function do its magic.
3. Do I need a `value` argument in this case? - since the integer value in the array will represent both the node and its value? (which will always be the same thing)

Comment: The way your BST class is currently written, it *cannot* represent an empty tree.  You'd need to pass the first element of the list in the `currentNode = BST()` line, and then call `.insert()` on the rest of the elements.

Comment: Thanks Jason, how would I do the first part of what you mentioned? i.e. pass the first element of the list in the currentNode = BST(), how does that look code wise, like this?: currentNode.value = array[0]? Than apply the for loop?

Comment: `currentNode = BST(array[0])` is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You may construct first node outside loop with the first item of the array.
2. If you need to access the node. So it can be returned as well.

```python
class BST: 
    def __init__(self,value): 
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.value = value

    def insert(self, value):
        if value<self.value: 
            if not self.left: 
                self.left = BST(value)   
            else: 
                self.left.insert(value)   
        else: 
            if not self.right: 
                self.right = BST(value)  
            else: 
                self.right.insert(value)
        return self

def insertArrayEntryIntoBst(array):
    currentNode = BST(array[0])
    for i in range(1,len(array)): 
      currentNode.insert(array[i])
    return(currentNode)

array = [3,10,5,2,7,6,11] 

myNode=insertArrayEntryIntoBst(array)
print(myNode.value);
print(myNode.left.value);
print(myNode.right.value);
```

Comment: I think you forgot the 'value' argument in the initialisation, but otherwise it looks good! Thanks

Comment: @Patrick_Chong , Thanks, I missed it.  i have edited and included it.